# After login only center of display is used and it's vertical (portrait)

Tags: display, lenovo, display-resolution

[image: desktop on display center only]

I just installed Ubuntu **20.04** on the Lenovo Miix 320. After installation the resolution was automatically configured to 1920x1200. I changed it to the correct resolution of 1200x800 and after that the desktop appears only in the center of the screen and it's vertical (see picture).

This only happens after the login screen. The login screen is showed correctly.

Comment: in the display, settings select orientation: `landscape` and select `max  resolution`

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I only have the options 'Resolution' (without 'max resolution' choice), 'Refresh Rate', and 'Fractional Scaling'. Nothing else.

Comment: What I mean is to choose the maximum resolution which is shown on your resolution option.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Setting the resolution at 1200x1920 fixes it. But that was the same (wrong) resolution that Ubuntu choose as default after install.

Changing to the maximum possible (or anything higher) causes the screen to flicker with distorted diagonal lines. Even then, the distortion is still limited to the center of the screen (same area as before).

I think I will have to keep the upscaled resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a program named "xrandr" to fix it.
Could you open a Terminal, type "xrandr", press Enter, and send the result of that?

Greetings, Eric

Comment: xrandr output:
https://pastebin.com/d8TBAvtb

Changing from `right` to `normal` on arandr rotates the desktop only within the central part of the display.

Comment: Oh Okay. Then i've got no idea, sorry